# Laravel - Is there any better approach to check the checkbox with the user previous input value in blade?

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I have a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example">
```

The user submits the form and return back due to failed validation so I want to show the previous state of the checkbox

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    name="example"
    {!! old('example') ? 'value="1" checked' : 'value="0"' !!}>
```

First question here is that, what to do with validation now? if it was `0` or `1` I would add boolean validation but now the first time it is `on` and after that it is `0` or `1`.

Someone may say if you use that `{!! old('example') ? 'value="1" checked' : 'value="0"' !!}` initially, its value won't be `on` anymore.

So my first question changes to this: Initially the value of `old('example')` is null so the checkbox doesn't have checked attribute and the value of checkbox would be `0`. Now when the user submits the form the `old('example')` has value (IT IS NOT NULL) and so this time the the checkbox has checked attribute and its value is `1` while it mustn't.

========

Another issue I encounter with is that, if `old('example')` has true value (which means the user had checked the checkbox), I should put something to check the checkbox. But it is not finished yet. I want to check the value of `example` that is in database so if the `old('example')` has false value(which means the user hadn't checked the checkbox) I want to check the value of `example`, if its value is `1` to check the checkbox and set the value of checkbox to 1 else 0. So what comes to my mind is this:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    name="example"
    value="{!! old('example', isset($collection) ? $collection->example : null) == '1' : '1' : '0' !!}">
```

Now the problem is that `old('example')` would be `on` or NOTHING. And the value of `$collection->example` would be `1` or `0` or null. So if I compare it with '1' it won't be true even if the `old('example')` is true and similarly if I compare it with `on`, it won't be true even if the value of `$collection->example` is true. So let's do this:

```
@if(old('example') == 'on' || (isset($collection) && $collection->example))
    <input type="checkbox" name="example" value="on" checked="checked">
@else
    <input type="checkbox" name="example">
@endif
```

by this code above the issue is fixed. But is there any other better approach?

So my question is what to do with the validation in the back-end and of course what to do with check-boxes in front-end in an better approach without getting involved in jQuery and such a like?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will solve your problem give it a try.

**Blade file:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example" value="{{ old('example') ?? '1' }}"
  {{ old('example') == '1' ? 'checked' : null }} required>
```

The required will force the user to check the checkbox on the frontend, and on the backend, you can use the required validation because we can't trust the frontend validation.

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'example' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```